# Light from smoke simulator doesn't travel outside domain

Tags: cycles-render-engine, smoke-simulation

Light emitted from the smoke simulator behaves normally inside of the domain but wont go outside it. Is there any way I can fix this or is it a bug?

Picture 1 is with light from fire and 2nd is with a point light.

[image: No light except for a few bounces go outside the smoke domain]

[image]

Comment: @icYou520 that is untrue. You made that up without much thinking about it, didn't you..

Comment: @JaroslavJerrynoNovotny I guess I read it to quick. I was thinking smoke not light. Erased previous comment. Although I think it had a different title when I first saw this weeks ago.

Answer (score 2):

I had the same problem. But after playing with the "Sampling"-settings of Cycle-renderer, I have by accident found the solution. Make sure that the number of "Diffuse" bounces is set to a minimum of 1. If it is 0, the light can´t pass through the domain.